# Как в Ansible зафорсить установку последних версий зависимостей с помощью npm?

Tags: npm, ansible

Есть в таске вызов `npm install` в проекте:

```
- name: call npm install for nodejs client
  npm: path={{api_dir}}
```

Всё отлично работает, если с нуля `install` вызывается. Если же ранее я уже вызывал его, то не обновляются некоторые зависимости до последнее версии. Пробовал с `state=latest` та же проблема.

Сейчас перед вызовом удаляю папку `node_modules`:

```
- name: remove nodejs client node_modules
  file: path={{api_dir}}/node_modules state=absent
  ignore_errors: true

- name: call npm install for nodejs client
  npm: path={{api_dir}}
```

Работает, но выглядит костыльно. Нельзя ли в Ansible что-то типо `npm install --force` сделать?

Comment: Там, на вид, скорее [`npm update`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update) сделать надо.

Answer (score 1):

Из коробки в [модуле npm](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/npm_module.html) опции `--force` сейчас нет. Так что если необходимо именно так, то тогда только использовать модуль shell .

Судя [по коду](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/blob/devel/packaging/language/npm.py#L253-L258) `npm update` дергается только если есть missing или outdated пакеты.